# Swift: Stopping a nested recursive function with an alert controller for user input

Tags: swift, recursion, uialertcontroller

I have a program that I'm working on that takes an array of strings and iterates through this list and creates a binary tree depending on what the user selects from a head to head matchup.

The problem is that I'm wanting to have the program stop and wait for the user to select an option within the alert controller before continuing through the nested recursive functions. It is not doing this. It actually runs through the code without stopping and displays the alert controller at the end.

I have one recursive function to iterate through the array and within each option I have a recursive function to place where in the binary tree i want the node to be created with the string name.

The code is pasted below.

```
func iterate(value: Int){
    
    if unsortedArray.count > value {
        addNode(name: unsortedArray[value])
        
    }
}

func addNode(name: String){
    
    if self.root == nil {
        
        self.root = Node(nameValue: name)
        
    } else {
        
        self.addNode(name: name, node: root!)
        
    }

    //raises the value of iterator int by one and calls the iterate function again to access the next string in the array

    iterator+=1
    self.iterate(value: iterator)
}

private func addNode(name: String, node: Node){
    
    
    showPopUp(name: name, node: node)
    

}

func showPopUp(name: String, node: Node){
    //calls an alert dialog using the names of the two string items as the names of the button. 
    
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Head to Head Comparison", message: "Select which item you prefer", preferredStyle: .alert)
    
    let nameAction = UIAlertAction(title: name, style: .default) { (UIAlertAction) in
    
        
        self.output.append("\(name) was selected over \(node.nodeName) \r\n")
        if node.rightChild == nil {
            
            node.rightChild = Node(nameValue: name)
            
        } else {
            
            
            self.addNode(name: name, node: node.rightChild!)
            
        }
    }
    let nodeAction = UIAlertAction(title: node.nodeName, style: .default) { (UIAlertAction) in
        
        
        self.output.append("\(node.nodeName) was selected over \(name) \r\n")
        
        if node.leftChild == nil {
            
            
            node.leftChild = Node(nameValue: name)
            
        } else {
            
            
            self.addNode(name: name, node: node.leftChild!)
            
        }
    }
    
    alert.addAction(nameAction)
    alert.addAction(nodeAction)
    

    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: "I'm wanting to have the program stop and wait for the user to select an option within the alert controller before continuing through the nested recursive functions. It is not doing this" You can't. Programs do not "stop and wait".

Comment: You should be able to use a UIAlertController, add an action to that alert controller (UIAlertAction), and use the optional handler parameter to execute a task after the completion of the action.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to figure out what your code was supposed to do (you didn't provide enough of it); but here's an example that shows you the general principle you need to imitate. You do not "recurse"; you show the alert and *stop*. The handlers of the buttons in the alert then call the traversal method again. In my example, we merely traverse an existing simple binary tree in accordance with the user's instructions. Skip to the bottom and focus your eyes on the `doQuery` method:

```
enum Dir {
    case left
    case right
}
class Node<T> where T: CustomStringConvertible {
    let value: T
    var left: Node?
    var right: Node?
    unowned var parent: Node?
    init(value: T) {
        self.value = value
    }
    func addChild(_ dir:Dir, value: T) {
        let child = Node(value:value)
        child.parent = self
        let kp = dir == .left ? \Node.left : \Node.right
        self[keyPath:kp] = child
    }
    func child(_ dir:Dir) -> Node<T>? {
        let kp = dir == .left ? \Node.left : \Node.right
        return self[keyPath:kp]
    }
    func path() -> String {
        let result = String(describing: self.value)
        if let parent = self.parent {
            return parent.path() + " -> " + result
        }
        return result
    }
}
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let graph = Node(value:"top")
    var current : Node<String>?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        graph.addChild(.left, value: "dog")
        graph.addChild(.right, value: "cat")
        if let dog = graph.child(.left) {
            dog.addChild(.left, value: "rover")
            dog.addChild(.right, value: "fido")
        }
        if let cat = graph.child(.right) {
            cat.addChild(.left, value: "whiskers")
            cat.addChild(.right, value: "frisky")
        }
    }
    @IBAction func doButton (_ sender:Any) {
        current = graph
        doQuery()
    }
    private func doQuery() {
        guard let currentNode = current,
              let left = currentNode.child(.left),
              let right = currentNode.child(.right)
                else {
            announceResult()
            return
        }
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Pick One", message: "Which do you prefer?", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: String(left.value), style: .default) { action in
            self.current = currentNode.child(.left)
            self.doQuery()
        })
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: String(right.value), style: .default) { action in
            self.current = currentNode.child(.right)
            self.doQuery()
        })
        self.present(alert, animated: true)
    }
    private func announceResult() {
        guard let result = current else { return }
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Done", message: "You chose \(result.path())", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
        self.present(alert, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out what the issue was.. I was pushing the loop of the string array outside of the alert controller vs. letting the alert controller pop up and then after the selection iterate to the next item of the array. Thank you all for the assistance. your comments helped to get me there.